# Curl equivalent to this openssl command

Tags: curl, openssl

How can I reciprocate this in curl:

```
openssl s_client -connect myhost.systems:myport -key server.key -cert cert.pem -CAfile ca.pem
```

I have been trying for a long while with the following curl command:

```
curl --key server.key --cert cert.pem --cacert ca.pem myhost:myport
```

but I get

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

---

EDIT:

Adding https:// to curl helps but I get 403 error. With openssl s_client everything works perfectly.

Comment: This actually helps. Now I get 403 error. With openssl s_client everything works perfectly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell curl that it should speak HTTPS by properly using that scheme in the URL:

```
curl --key server.key --cert cert.pem --cacert ca.pem https://myhost:myport
```

Comment: Adding https:// to curl helps but I get 403 error. With openssl s_client everything works perfectly.

Comment: Well, a 403 means that the server dislikes something in the HTTP layer, so try changing the curl request to look more like the openssl one...

Comment: I can open the site with chrome(ubuntu) and I actually copied the curl from InspectElement->Network feature.